# how to set a max date

Tags: jquery, datetime, picker

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo theme_js('jquery.simple-dtpicker.js')?>"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo theme_css('jquery.simple-dtpicker.css')?>" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var now = new Date();
var yourDate = now.getDate()  + '/' + (now.getMonth() + 3) + '/' + now.getFullYear();
//alert(today);
$('#date_tim').appendDtpicker({
"futureOnly": true,"autodateOnStart": false,"setDate": yourDate,"minTime":"10:00","maxTime":"18:00","closeOnSelected": true
});

</script>
```

Comment: in jquery datepicker you can use {maxDate: "+2M"} means +2 months from current date. Which one are you using??

Comment: i'm using datetimepicker,this is the one (http://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/jquery.simple-dtpicker.html)                      {maxDate: "+2M"} is not working for me i have used that one

Comment: i want to know how to use the var youdate in my setDate.how to use that...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting the date range:

```
   $('#date_tim').appendDtpicker({
            maxDate : '2016/11/10',
            minDate: '2016/09/10'        
        });
```

For setting a date you can use the below code:

```
$('#date_tim').handleDtpicker('setDate', new Date(2016, 09, 10, 0, 0, 0));
```

You need to mention whatever date and time you want to set inside the new `Date();`

Comment: thanks a lot this works but how to set minDate as current date and max date as +3 months...?

Comment: Get the current date and make the substrings accordingly and then pass to the setDate function.Do the same for setting maxDate, get the current date add +3 months and format the string accordingly.

Comment: @GunasekarDNM, You can mark the answer as accepted and give an upvote if it worked out for you so that it will be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Define Maxdate without hardcoding:-

```
function dateP() {
    var today = new Date();
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        maxDate: "-1d"
    });
    $(".datepickerYesterday").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        maxDate: "-1d"
    }).datepicker("setDate", -1);
    $('.datepickerMonthlyReport').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        maxDate: "-1M",
        dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
        onChange: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        },
        beforeShow: function(el, dp) {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('hide-calendar');
        },
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('hide-calendar');
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 1));
};
```